# Python, sort array with respect to a sub-array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following array:

```
master_array = [[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
                [9. 8. 4. 5. 1.]]
```

I would like to sort the master_array with respect to the second sub-array so that the relationship between first sub-array and second sub-array is maintained

```
master_array = [[5. 3. 4. 2. 1.] 
                [1. 4. 5. 8. 9.]]
```

Thank You

Comment: Why is this tagged with numpy? What you are showing here is a *list*.

Comment: So, I tried searching how to arrange an array with respect to a sub-array, was not able to find anything substantial yet.

Sorry, forgot the dots after the numbers.

Comment: what are those dots mean ?

Comment: That's how array is constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert list to numpy array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> master_array = [[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.], [9.,8.,4.,5.,1.]]
>>> n=np.array(master_array)
>>> n
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 9.,  8.,  4.,  5.,  1.]])
```

Assign index values for the second array so take `n[1]`

```
>>> temp=list(enumerate(n[1]))
>>> temp
[(0, 9.0), (1, 8.0), (2, 4.0), (3, 5.0), (4, 1.0)]
```

sort the  array with respect to array elements

```
>>> list1=sorted(temp,key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> list1
[(4, 1.0), (2, 4.0), (3, 5.0), (1, 8.0), (0, 9.0)]
```

Take all the indexes from sorted result and store in a seperate array

```
>>> a=[i[0] for i in list1 ]
>>> a
[4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
```

Use indexing of columns in numpy on the numpy array

```
>>> n[:,a]
array([[ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  5.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Comment: That's beautiful! Do you mind explaining what each of the steps does?

Comment: @IsaacA i have modified the answer pls check

Comment: Hello Paul, that's quite a brilliant solution. Thank you for your help. Explanations make sense. I found the last part to be somewhat challenging, but after some thinking I understood what is happening.