# Is there a way to sort a tensor with respect to a sub array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to sort a tensor with respect to a sub-array.
For example, I have a following tensor:

```py
A = tf.constant([[4, 2, 1, 7, 5], 
                 [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]])
```

And I want to sort this tensor A respect to the A[0, :].

The result I expect is:

```py
A = tf.constant([[1, 2, 4, 5, 7], 
                 [30, 20, 10, 50, 40]])
```

I saw a similar question in stack overflow. ([Python, sort array with respect to a sub-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417679/python-sort-array-with-respect-to-a-sub-array))

But that question is about python array, and the answer doesn't apply to my problem.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Is extracting the tensor data to an python array and re-defining the tensor not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tf.gather` with `tf.argsort`:

```
import tensorflow as tf:

a = tf.constant([[4, 2, 1, 7, 5], 
                 [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]])

b = tf.gather(a, tf.argsort(a[0]), axis=1)
b
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=152, shape=(2, 5), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  2,  4,  5,  7],
       [30, 20, 10, 50, 40]])>
```

Comment: You're awesome! I've seen the `tf.gather` and `tf.argsort` documentations before, but I didn't know how to apply them properly. I spent quite a long time for this... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `argsort` function on `A[0, :]` to compute the column ordering and the `gather` function to compute the new tensor. Cf. [tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([[4, 2, 1, 7, 5],
     [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]])

tf.gather(A, tf.argsort(A[0, :]), axis=1)
```